# Maximization of quadratic form over complex unit cube

Tags: optimization, quadratic-forms

I am trying to find the maximum of a hermitian positive definite quadratic form $xQx^H$ (where $Q=Q^H$ and all eigenvalues of $Q$ are non-negative) over the complex unit cube $|x_i|\leq 1$, $i=1,\dots,n$  where $x=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)\in\mathbb{C}^n$.

This is the problem of minimizing a concave function over a convex domain. I have read that this problem is NP-hard but there exist some bounds on the optimum (see http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.122.6954&rep=rep1&type=pdf ) . What global optimization technique would your recommend to tackle this problem numerically? Since I am new to the field of optimization, I would appreciate every answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As the cube is convex and compact, it is the convex hull of its extreme points (by Krein-Milman theorem or in case of cube by its simple geometry). As the objective is convex and continuous, it has a global maximizer and one of them is an extreme point of the cube.

Comment: As far as I have read, the standard form of convex optimization problems is to minimize an objective function. In this case, maximization of $xQx^H$ would mean minimization of $-xQx^H$, which is not convex. Do I miss something? Even if the maximum lies on an extreme point of the cube, how do you define a "vertex" on complex cube? If it is the set $|x_i|=1$ $\forall i$, then one still has an optimization problem over the Cartesian product of the phases of $x_i$, i.e. over $[0,2\pi]^n$.

Comment: you are right. it seems, you still have to optimize over the phases. it is manageable but surely not beautiful.